# PySimpleGUI radio button return text, not True/False

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to create an easy form to quickly populate an excel file.

The columns in the final excel file are 'Number' (enter an ID number), 'Other Details'(to enter text if specific details need adding), then several columns that relate to attributes of the objects I'm trying to record, which each have several options.

For these latter columns I've seen that radio buttons in PySimpleGUI return True/False, when I'd like to just have the text of the radio buttons saved in a single column. How do I go about turning the True/False for each button into just the text related to the buttons?

Solution below:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

EXCEL_FILE = 'data_entry.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

lst = ('English', 'Chinese', 'Japanese', 'Russian')
lst2 = ('English', 'Chinese', 'Japanese', 'Russian')
lst3 = ('English', 'Chinese', 'Japanese', 'Russian')
lst4 = ('English', 'Chinese', 'Japanese', 'Russian')
lst5 = ('English', 'Chinese', 'Japanese', 'Russian')

layout = [
[sg.Input('', key='INPUT 1')], 
[sg.Radio(text, "Radio", enable_events=True, key=f"Radio {i}")
    for i, text in enumerate(lst)],
[sg.Radio(text, "Radio2", enable_events=True, key=f"Radio2 {i}")
    for i, text in enumerate(lst2)],
[sg.Radio(text, "Radio3", enable_events=True, key=f"Radio3 {i}")
    for i, text in enumerate(lst3)],
[sg.Radio(text, "Radio4", enable_events=True, key=f"Radio4 {i}")
    for i, text in enumerate(lst4)],
[sg.Radio(text, "Radio5", enable_events=True, key=f"Radio5 {i}")
    for i, text in enumerate(lst5)],
[sg.Input('', key='INPUT 2')],

[sg.Push(), sg.Button("Go"), sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window("test", layout, finalize=True)

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == 'Go':
        """
        radio_value = window[event].TKIntVar.get()
        col = radio_value % 1000                        # count from 0
        row = (radio_value - col) % 100000              # count from 0
        container = radio_value // 100000               # count from 1
        # print(container, row, col)
        """
        radio_value = window['Radio 0'].TKIntVar.get()
        text = lst[radio_value % 1000] if radio_value else None
    
        radio_value2 = window['Radio2 0'].TKIntVar.get()
        text2 = lst2[radio_value2 % 1000] if radio_value2 else None
    
        radio_value3 = window['Radio3 0'].TKIntVar.get()
        text3 = lst2[radio_value3 % 1000] if radio_value3 else None       
    
        radio_value4 = window['Radio4 0'].TKIntVar.get()
        text4 = lst2[radio_value4 % 1000] if radio_value4 else None

        radio_value5 = window['Radio5 0'].TKIntVar.get()
        text5 = lst2[radio_value5 % 1000] if radio_value5 else None
    
        record = [values['INPUT 1'], text, text2, text3, text4, text5, values['INPUT 2']]
        print(record)
        df = df.append(record, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        sg.popup('Data saved!')
        clear_input()

window.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the text directly from event values for it is defined as an integer variable to store the value, but you can get it by `element.Text`.

To get the values of elements, you can get them from dictionary `values`. For lot of Radio elements, you can scan which radio with value `True` or find the code in following script to get the selected index.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

lst = ('English', 'Chinese', 'Japanese', 'Russian')

layout = [
    [sg.Input('', key='INPUT 1')],
    [sg.Radio(text, "Radio", enable_events=True, key=f"Radio {i}")
        for i, text in enumerate(lst)],
    [sg.Input('', key='INPUT 2')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("Go"), sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window("test", layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event.startswith("Radio"):
        text = window[event].Text
        print(text)
    elif event == 'Go':
        """
        radio_value = window[event].TKIntVar.get()
        col = radio_value % 1000                        # count from 0
        row = (radio_value - col) % 100000              # count from 0
        container = radio_value // 100000               # count from 1
        # print(container, row, col)
        """
        radio_value = window['Radio 0'].TKIntVar.get()
        text = lst[radio_value % 1000] if radio_value else None
        record = [values['INPUT 1'], text, values['INPUT 2']]
        print(record)

window.close()
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. I can see this prints the text from the radio button which is perfect. 

My problem now is I'm struggling to modify your answer to deal with multiple radio buttons and my other elements. My layout is an InputText field, 5x Radio buttons, then a final InputText field. 

How do I combine these into a list (that I can then write to a excel file, which I've already set up)?

Comment: Update as above.

Comment: I've added my (nearly) final code in the question above.

Comment: You can check which value is `True` to confirm which indexed item selected, then get the text from the `lst` if you have it after any event. You can get all the strings and use some library to create an excel file or update to an excel file, like `openpyxl` whch is a Python library to allow you to read and write Excel files using an easy code, thus enabling people to improve work performance.